# Elementos dinámicos con Selenium y Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy intentando rellenar un pequeño formulario con Selenium, pero tiene elementos dinámicos que no deja capturar de ninguna manera. En este enlace aparece el formulario: https://www.asefasalud.es/

[image: Como se muestra el elemento]

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'inputDiafnac')]").get(0).send_keys("2") driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'inputDiafnac')]").send_keys("2") driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='inputDiafnac1']").send_keys("2") driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#inputDiafnac1").send_keys("2") driver.find_element_by_id("inputDiafnac1").send_keys("2")`

He probado con casi todos los elementos de búsqueda para capturar el objeto pero ninguno resulta:
[image: Terminal tras compilar]

No sé, sí habrá otra forma de capturar estos elementos, gracias.

Comment: Resuelto en Stack overflow=> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67005092/dynamic-elements-with-selenium-and-python.

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor agregar tu mismo la respuesta? Así si otro usuario tiene el mismo problema podría encontrar la solución en español.

Comment: @FranAcuna claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resulta que los elementos de este formulario, se encuentran dentro de frame (marco) y por eso Selenium necesita que le indiques, una búsqueda específica en dicho frame.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='calcular-seguro-medico']"))
#Ejemplo rellenar formulario: driver.find_element_by_id("inputDiafnac1").send_keys("2")
```

Con ese código ya estaríamos dentro del frame, para poder trabajar con normalidad en el formulario. Tras trabajar en el frame debemos indicarle a Selenium que salga de él, de la siguiente forma:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```